# Find the values of $p$ for which this sequence of functions uniformly converges.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Show that $f_n\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by

$$f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{1+n^2x^p}.$$

For $p>0$, Find the values of $p$ for which the sequence $f_n$ converges uniformly to the limit.

My attempt:
What's clear is that the sequence converges pointwise to the function $f(x)=0$.
With trial and error, I noticed that the power of $x$ should be less than the power of $n$ which is $2$. Therefore $p$ should be $1$. 
Am I thinking properly? And how to show this?

Comment: Since $f_n$ is a non-negative function with $f_n(0) = 0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f_n(x) = 0$, it attains a maximum somewhere. Find the location and value.

Comment: Is $p$ necessarily a positive INTEGER ?

Comment: It's a positive real number. @DanielWainfleet

Comment: Re your comment after the A by Dr. MV, the AGM (Arithmetic-Geometric Mean(s)) Inequality is $(\sum_{i=1}^nA_i)/n\geq (\prod_{i=1}^nA_i)^{(1/n)}$ for positive $A_1,..., A_n$, with equality iff  the $A_i$ are all equal.

Answer (score 1):

We assume that $x\ge 0$, else $x^p$ is in general undefined for $x<0$.

The pointwise limit as $n\to \infty$ is zero.  We will analyze four cases to determine for which values of $p$ this convergence is uniform.

We will see that the "problems" arise for "large" $x$ when $0<p<1$ and for "small" $x$ when $p>2$.

---

**CASE $1$: $\displaystyle 0<p<1$**

Suppose that $0<p<1$.  Take $\epsilon=\frac12$.  Then, for all $N\ge 1$ we take $x=n^{2/(1-p)}$ and any $n>N$ and find

$$\left|\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^p}\right|\ge \frac12 =\epsilon$$

This negates uniform convergence for $0<p<1$ and $x\in [0,\infty)$.

---

**CASE $2$: $\displaystyle 2 \ge p$**

Suppose that $p\ge 2$.  Take $\epsilon=1/2$.  Then for all $N\ge 1$, we take $x=n^{-2/p}$ and any $n>N$ such that

$$\left|\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^p}\right|=\frac12 n^{1-2/p}\ge \frac12$$

And the convergence fails to be uniform for $x\in [0,\infty)$.

---

**CASE $3$: $\displaystyle p=1$**

Note the for $p=1$ we have

$$\left|\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^p}\right|\le \frac1n$$

And the convergence is uniform.

---

**CASE $4$: $\displaystyle 1 < p<2$**

For $1<p<2$, we find that $f_n'(x)=0$ at $x=\left((p-1)n^2\right)^{-1/p}$.  At that value of $x$, $f_n(x)=\frac{(p-1)^{1-1/p}}{p}n^{1-2/p}\to 0$. And convergence in the sup norm implies uniform convergence.

---

**PUTTING IT ALL TOGETHER:**

> The sequence $f_n(x)=\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^p}$ converges uniformly to $0$ for $x\in [0,\infty)$ when $1\le p<2$.  The convergence fails to be uniform for $p<1$ and fails to be uniform for $p\ge 2$.

Comment: What is the AM-GM inequality? I don't know it :(

Comment: Why did you exclude negative x?

Comment: If $x<0$, then $x^p$ is in general undefined on the reals.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark